# Caught segfault (R call C)

Tags: r, segmentation-fault

I got the error message,
         *** caught segfault *** address 0x10, cause 'memory not mapped' 
   when I used the .c function in R in Linux. I've check if there's something wrong
   with the allocation and deallocation of pointers, but I can't find any bugs so far.
   And it's weird that I can execute the .c function in R in Windows.

Thanks for your help.

P.S.
    Here is some part of the allocation and deallocation of the pointers in my c code:

```
double **x;
x= (double **)calloc(nRow ,sizeof(double*));
for(i = 0; i < nRow; ++i)
 x[i] = (double *)calloc(nCol, sizeof(double));

....

 for(i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
    free(x[i]);
 free(x);
```

Comment: You are obviously not seeing wherer the code goes wrong, so why are you posting only part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. You probably have a memory bug elsewhere that results in `x` being corrupted.

[`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) might be able to help.